# How to add the category on preference header?

Tags: android, preference-headers

I have a simple `preference_headers.xml` file. I want to add some categories on my preference headers. I have tried to implement `<PreferenceCategory />` in my `preference_headers.xml`, but it doesn't work. I'm using API level 11. As shown in the figure below, Android Developers from [official website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders) can add the categories. How can I add it too?

[image: categories on preference header]

And here is a few of my `preference_headers.xml` code. It won't work:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="ACCOUNT" > 

        <header android:fragment="com.example.preferenceheader.SettingsFragmentAccount"
            android:title="@string/pref_header_category_account"
            android:summary="@string/pref_header_summ_account"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="APPLICATION" >

        <header android:fragment="com.example.preferenceheader.SettingsFragmentApplication"
            android:title="@string/pref_header_category_application"
            android:summary="@string/pref_header_summ_application"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_group" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</preference-headers>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: dont you need actual preferences?

Comment: what is actual preference? I don't understand.

Comment: checkout http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment.html they have explained it wonderfully.

Comment: @Rohan Kandwal, Thanks for your answer before. I have learned from the site you give, but it doesn't explain about adding the categories.

Comment: There was one more link there. It's a set of two tutorials, see this link, it might fulfill your requirement http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment_28.html

Comment: @RohanKandwal, The site you give doesn't explain about add the category too.

Comment: Note: If you're developing your application for Android 3.0 and higher, you should instead use PreferenceFragment. Go to the next section about Using Preference Fragments. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

Comment: Solve this yet?  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @lostintranslation, I still facing this problem.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot how the screen looks like with your current xml code?

Comment: @TristanVanderaerden, if I use above XML code, the app will crash. So, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It's been close to a year since this was asked but I run into this example at http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/preference-settings.html that I think describes the requirement of the question in great detail and explanation.

I hope that it will help someone as it has helped me since it details the process of building a preference screen with categories and headers on the same page!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need add header with only title. For example settings from AOSP

```
<!-- WIRELESS and NETWORKS -->
<header android:title="@string/header_category_wireless_networks" />

<!-- Wifi -->
<header
    android:id="@+id/wifi_settings"
    android:fragment="com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings"
    android:title="@string/wifi_settings_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_wireless" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is entirely correct. The header with a single title, as proposed in your response, becomes a separate clickable header item when I try. Worth mentioning is that I'm using the `android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment` which, in some mysterious way, may affect the outcome...